# How can I connect Microsoft Teams to my web?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to connect my web app to Microsoft Teams. 
If a client connects to my website, he will see the chats or make video calls in a part of the view and in the other one, I could have whatever.

I have been seen the graph API but it's not exactly that, because when I create an online meeting, the response returns me a link to Microsoft Teams web.
Finally, if I try to encapsulate this response inside an iframe, I get the next error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPomj.png)

In resume, it would be like an Microsoft teams client embedded into my website, is it possible?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to implement Teams client embedded inside your web page. Just a link on a page to https://teams.microsoft.com gets you to the full app.

If you implement all the functionality inside embedded view, then things would become squashed into a smaller space than needed.